# WPF Canvas OnRender behavior

Tags: wpf, canvas

I try to realize the correct behavior in the overrided `OnRender` method in the custon `Canvas`. I face with the magic number 4 and can't find it's source.

Example of my override is below. The managers like `m_<ManagerName>M` are separeted classes that do the draw logic.

```
  public class MyCanvas : Canvas {
    ...
    int m_counter = 0;
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        m_counter++;

        if (m_counter == 4 && Leasings != null)
        {
            m_counter = 0;
            ClearManagers();

            if (m_gridM != null)
            {
                var rowsI = Leasings.Select(l => l.RowIndex).Distinct();
                foreach (var i in rowsI)
                    m_gridM.DrawRow(i, dc);

                m_gridM.DrawColumns(DayCount, dc);
            }

            if (m_barM != null)
            {
                foreach (var bm in Leasings)
                {
                    m_barM.DrawBar(bm, dc);
                }
            }

            if (m_textM != null)
            {
                m_textM.Load(Leasings);
                m_textM.DrawText(dc);
            }
        }

        base.OnRender(dc);
    }
...
}
```

The problem is I can't understand why this method have called 4th times in a row on window loaded (or what the first action is) and 3 or 2 times when the binded data has been changed.

I have got that draw have happend successfully on 4th iteration only. I don't know why and added the counter with the condition for 4th iteration. It works fine.

When I tried to redraw I got only 3 or sometimes 2 calls of the `OnRender`. So the condition for draw is not working and even if I change it for this case the data have not been drawed.

What my actions do fire the `OnRender` method? Why the draw is successfull on the last call `OnLoad` and not hapend (or visible) when I try to refresh the data?

Comment: You should only override OnRender when you are sure that you need to, and clearly understand why and when it is called. If you would explain what you are actually trying to achieve, we might help you with a far more simple and appropriate approach.

Comment: I need to draw the specific chart. I tried to achive it with Grids and ItemsCollections with templates but it was too slow. Now this solution draw about 3000 objects like lines, rectangles and texts about 1-2 seconds and that is what i need. But i can't find helpfull references for some Canvas rendering manuals or so to understand this strange behavior as for me.

Comment: It's still unclear why you need to derive from Canvas. Better use a DrawingVisual as explained in [Using DrawingVisual Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects#drawingvisual-host-container).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks a lot! I didn't think that it poissible to draw fast in WPF without `Canvas` so decided to make solution with it. I have replaced `Canvas` with `FrameworkElement` with `DrawindVisual` strategy from examples and it works as i whant.